# How to schedule a workflow in argoproj?

Tags: argoproj, argo-workflows

I wrote a workflow in argoproj workflow and I want to execute it let's say every 1 hour. In plane k8s I would use CronJob kind for this task. What should I use?

Answer (score 2):

Argo 2.5 [introduced](https://blog.argoproj.io/argo-workflows-v2-5-released-ce7553bfd84c) a new ["CronWorkflow" type](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/docs/cron-workflows.md).

This slight variation of their example workflow will run every hour:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: CronWorkflow
metadata:
  name: test-cron-wf
spec:
  schedule: "0 * * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: "Replace"
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 0
  workflowSpec:
    entrypoint: whalesay
    templates:
    - name: whalesay
      container:
        image: alpine:3.6
        command: [sh, -c]
        args: ["date; sleep 90"]
```